# kotlin - get image from image array in drawable folder

Tags: android, kotlin, android-drawable, android-resources

I want to return my array of images from resource , this is my array for example :

```
 <integer-array name="drawer_icons">
    <item>@drawable/drawer_home</item>
</integer-array>
```

I get the array by this code:

```
val imagesArray =resources.getIntArray(R.array.drawer_icons)
```

the problem is , after the above code ,imagesArray has a value of 0

how can I return drawable array from resources ?

---

EDIT:
I've made some changes in my codes, I've got another problem , I need to make a data class from these arrays , this is my code:

```
data class DrawerModel(var title:String, var img: Any)

val titlesArray=resources.getStringArray(R.array.drawer_titles)
    val imagesArray =resources.obtainTypedArray(R.array.drawer_icons)

    val list= ArrayList<DrawerModel>()
    for (i in titlesArray.indices){
        val model=DrawerModel(titlesArray[i],imagesArray[i])
        list.add(model)
    }
```

I've an error on imagesArray[i] , what should be the type of img in DrawerModel class? I've tried any , Int , String but non of them works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Kotlin , you can do as :-

```
 <integer-array name="drawer_icons">
    <item>@drawable/drawer_home</item>
</integer-array>
```

// You will get array of Image from resource as TypedArray

```
 val imageArray = resources.obtainTypedArray(R.array.drawer_icons)
```

// get resource ID by the index

```
imageArray.getResourceId(imageArray.getIndex(0),-1)
```

// OR you can set imageView's resource to the id

```
imageView.setImageResource(imageArray.getResourceId(imageArray.getIndex(0),-1))
```

// and in last recycle the array

```
imageArray.recycle()
```

For your extending of question , solution would be :-

```
 data class DrawerModel(var title:String, var img: Int)

 val titlesArray=resources.getStringArray(R.array. drawer_titles)
 val imagesArray =resources.obtainTypedArray(R.array. drawer_icons)

 val list= ArrayList<DrawerModel>()
 for (i in titlesArray.indices){
      val model=DrawerModel(titlesArray[i],imagesArray.getResourceId(imagesArray.getIndex(i),-1))
      list.add(model)
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use [TypedArray](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#TypedArray)

> A TypedArray defined in XML. You can use this to create an array of
>   other resources, such as drawables.

Example :

XML

```
<integer-array name="drawer_icons">
    <item>@drawable/drawer_home</item>
</integer-array>
```

Kotlin

```
val imageArray = resources.obtainTypedArray(R.array.drawer_icons)
val drawable: Drawable = imageArray.getDrawable(0)
```

Comment: thanks for reply , I've made the changes now I've some other problems, could you check my edited post

Comment: answer edited: you have to use Drawable for example

Answer (score 1):

This is not just an int array. You should use

`val imagesArray = resources.obtainTypedArray(R.array.drawer_icons)`

`val icon = imagesArray.getResourceId(position, -1)`

And don't forget to call `imagesArray.recycle()` after using it.

Comment: thanks for reply , I've made the changes now I've some other problems, could you check my edited post ?

Comment: @NavidAbutorab this is `@DrawableRes imgage: Int`